# format field values for a list of case class

Tags: scala

I have a `case class Person(id: Int, name: String, city: String)`.

`List[Person]` has following values loaded from the csv:

```
1,John,Illinois
2,Peter,Los Angeles
3,Chris,Dallas
```

How do I get a string output like below, using List[Person]:

```
(1,'John','Illinois'), (2,'Peter','Los Angeles'), (3,'Chris','Dallas')
```

Comment: Maybe `personList.flatMap(Person.unapply(_)).mkString(", ")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to go from `List[Person]` to `List[Tuple3[Int,String,String]]`.

This should do it:

```
persons.map(p => (p.id, p.name, p.city))
```

If you want the `String` representation then add `.mkString(",")` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a string output not a list.

Answer (score 2):

Using string interpolation + `mkString` would be probably the most straightforward way to achieve exactly output your described:

```
personList.map(p => s"(${p.id},'${p.name}','${p.city}')").mkString(", ")
```